# TeXworks how to view two pages of a document at once?

Tags: windows, texworks, viewers

Adobe Acrobat has this feature and in fact it also has the feature that the first page of the document is displayed alone. Then from page 2 onwards two pages are being shown every time. This gives the impression that you are reading a book.

Is it possible to view two pages at once in TeXworks (not TeXmaker) ? So far i can't find any. Maybe there is a plugin, an extension or something?

Comment: Version 0.6.0 featured a lot of improvements to the PDF viewer, including two-page view, see https://github.com/TeXworks/texworks/releases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Edit > Preferences`, `Preview` tab, `Page Mode`, select `Two pages continuous`:

[image]